# Не всплывает окно

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

У меня есть кнопка и при нажатии на неё должно всплывать окно через `fadeIn()` jQuery. Всё предельно просто, вот устройство программы.

Сюда производится ТЫК И появляется по факту это (п/п - результат в виджете)

Вот у нас есть скрипт

```js
document.getElementById('baton').onclick = function() {
  $('#coders').fadeIn();
}
```

```css
#coders {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="baton">
  <p style="text-align: center;" class="landing_text">Разработчики</p>
</div>
```

По факут должно работать. Не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ достаточно простой - у вас нет элемента с id `coders`. В итоге применить `fadeIn` не к чему. Момент номер 2 - пустой див `#baton` не имеет своей длинны и высоты и потому фактически невидим. И поэтому вызвать событие клик вы не сможете, пока не выставите ему хоть какуе-то высоту (т.к. дочерний элемент скрыт у дива будет нулевая высота), чтобы на него можно было нажать.
Вот мой вариант:

```js
document.getElementById('block').onclick = function() {
  $('#label').fadeIn();
}
```

```css
#label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35%;
  left: -10%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#block {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <p id="label" class="landing_text">Разработчики</p>
</div>
```

Comment: #baton как раз таки имеет длину и высоту, с ним нет проблем, а про первое уточните пожалуйста

Comment: элемент с идом #coders тоже есть, у него так же и длина и высота присутствует

Comment: В вашем примере дочерний элемент скрыт по умолчанию (display:none) и потому родительский блок будет пустым и иметь нулевую высоту

Comment: еще раз проверьте ваш html (я специально не исправлял) и убедитесь что блока с id = coders у вас нет

Comment: спасибо, плюсик вам)